# Selecionar cidades dos clientes no banco e contar quantos clientes existem em cada cidade

Tags: erp, abap

Preciso selecionar as cidades  dos clientes cadastrados no banco, e contar quantos clientes existe em cada cidade.

gostaria de saber como faço para saber se  o nome que estou pegando do banco já existe na tabela.

no momento estou tentando montar a tabela com os nomes das cidades sem repetir o nomes delas.

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF gy_city
 , name(30) TYPE c
 , qtd      TYPE i
 , END OF gy_city.

DATA: gs_kna1 TYPE kna1
, gs_city TYPE gy_city
, gt_kna1 TYPE TABLE OF kna1
, gt_city TYPE TABLE OF gy_city.



SELECT kunnr name1 regio mcod3 
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE gt_kna1
FROM kna1 
WHERE regio eq 'PR'.

LOOP AT gt_kna1 INTO gs_kna1.
  IF gs_kna1-mcod3 IN gt_city-name.
  WRITE 'ADICIONADO'.
  gs_city-name = gs_kna1-mcod3.
  APPEND gs_city to gt_city.
ELSE.
  WRITE 'REPETIDO'.
ENDIF.

ENDLOOP.
```

Encontrei essa solução:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF gy_city
     , name(30) TYPE c
     , qtd      TYPE i
     , END OF gy_city.

DATA: gs_kna1 TYPE kna1
    , gt_kna1 TYPE TABLE OF kna1
    , gt_city TYPE SORTED TABLE OF gy_city WITH UNIQUE KEY name
    , gs_city LIKE LINE  OF gt_city
    , gd_city_name(30) TYPE c.


* Select para table
SELECT mcod3 INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE gt_kna1 FROM kna1 WHERE regio EQ 'PR'ORDER BY mcod3 ASCENDING.

LOOP AT gt_kna1 INTO gs_kna1.

  READ TABLE gt_city
    INTO gs_city
    WITH KEY name = gs_kna1-mcod3.

  IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
    gs_city-qtd = gs_city-qtd + 1.
    MODIFY gt_city FROM gs_city INDEX sy-tabix.

  ELSE.
    gs_city-name = gs_kna1-mcod3.
    gs_city-qtd  = 1.
    APPEND gs_city TO gt_city.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
*SORT gt_city BY name ASCENDING.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renan,

Se você tiver uma tabela com as cidades e uma com os clientes e nessa tabela vc tem o id da cidade. Pode ser feito da seguinte forma.

```
select c.nomeCidade, count(*) quantidadeClientes from cidades c
inner join clientes cl on c.IdCidade = cl.IdCidade
group by c.nomeCidade
```

O resultado seria algo como:

```
nomeCidade       quantidadeClientes
São Paulo        10
Rio de Janeiro   5
Bahia            3
Acre             0
```

Comment: As cidades são cadastradas no kna1 junto com o cadastro dos clientes.